# How to store the array which is passed to an function, KSH?

Tags: ksh

As we have dynamic scoping in KSH, we can access the variable values from the called function. But I am failing storing those values. Please help in doing this.

```
#!/bin/ksh
fun1(){
eval echo "\${$1[@]}"
}
fun2(){
set -A var1 val1 val2 val3 val4
fun1 var1
}
fun2
```

I want to store the value of  **eval echo "\${$1[@]}"** in an new array. I've tried as below.

```
fun1(){
set -A array1 `eval echo "\${$1[@]}"`
echo " ${array[@]} "
}
```

But not working.How to store those values.

Comment: I have tried **set -A vari=\`eval \${$1[@]}\`** , not worked

Comment: It worked for me finally **set -A vari $(eval echo \${$1[@]})**, comment me if it is not useful question. I will remove from site.
But I didn't understand why **set -A array1 \`eval echo "\${$1[@]}"\`** not worked

Answer (score 2):

In ksh93 functions you can define a local variable as a *namereference* with `typeset -n` or `nameref`.

```
$ function f1 { nameref a=$1; echo ${a[1]}; }
$ set -A arry fee fie foe fum
$ f1 arry
fie
$ set -A barry foo bar
$ f1 barry
bar
```

A namereference can point to different types: arrays, associative arrays (maps), etc.